# How to detect set_user_setting event in Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, sublimetext, event-listener, sublime-text-plugin

I would like to work with an event which fires when I change the `color_scheme` setting located inside `Preferences.sublime-settings` for a plugin I'm writing for [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com).

I've [read](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) to use `on_window_command` of `EventListener` but it seems it doesn't fire.

```
class MyPluginEvents(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_window_command(self, window, command_name, args):
        print " --- FIRE! --- "
```

I've also tried `post_window_command` without success. Is there any way to detect when the preferences change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those docs you linked to are for ST3. [Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) are the docs for ST2. Note there is not `on_window_command`. That aside, you may want to take a look at `Settings#add_on_change`. I've never used that method in the API before, but based on the description, it should do what you want.

**Edit**

Know you have solution already, but adding this for anyone else that comes by this.
You would likely tie into an event, such as `on_load` or `on_new` so the command will run on any newly created view.

```
import sublime_plugin

class TestCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        settings = self.view.settings()
        settings.add_on_change("color_scheme", self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        print(self.view.settings().get("color_scheme"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure on how I shoud register callbacks in `add_on_change` can you help me with an example?

Comment: I've did it with `on_deactivated`

Comment: I know you have a solution, but I added an example if you care to look.